# Backreferencing regex in apache

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, symfony, mod-rewrite

I was setting up symfony framework for my system and configuring the .htaccess file to reroute requests when i came across these two lines:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
```

this is supposed to give us the rewrite base for the proceeding rewrites.
I want to know how $1 is processed here since there are no rewriterules preceding it?
and some clarification on how this code works would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$1` is the last rule capture group. It's a little confusing because of the way rules are processed by mod_rewrite. Given your rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
```

This is what mod_rewrite does:

1. I have a URI, let's apply this rule
2. I look at the `RewriteRule` line and checks the pattern: URI matches ^(.*), ok good, let's continue
3. Now let's check the conditions
4. The `%{REQUEST_URI}::$1` string gets mapped out to the URI and my first capture group, which happened in step 2
5. The pattern in condition matches, apply the target of the rule
6. The target is `-`, pass the URI through and apply the flags

So the rule gets "halfway" applied first, that's how the `$1` capture group gets set, then the conditions get checked.

Note that if you had:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^.* - [E=BASE:%1]
```

`$1` would be blank because the pattern in the rule doesn't have a capture group.

The `\2` is an inline back reference, so it references:

```
this----v
^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
```

grouping.

An example of how that condition works, is say we have the `%{REQUEST_URI}` of `/abc/foo/bar.html`, and say those rules are in the `/abc/` directory. That means the condition string:

```
%{REQUEST_URI}::$1
```

is

```
/abc/foo/bar.html::foo/bar.html
```

And the match takes the part after the `::` and matches the same thing before the `::`:

```
this bit ----------v__________v
/abc/foo/bar.html::foo/bar.html
     ^-----------^____must match this grouping
```

And thus, what is left is the first grouping `(/.+)`, which is `/abc/`. And now we have the correct relative URI base, stored in the environment variable "BASE".

Comment: Thanks man.that clarified a lot of things.but i still don't know how "\2" could match our $1 since \2 is $1 without the part before the first slash.i think that has something to do with the full url and the REQUEST_URI .could you clarify that too.perhaps with an example.

Comment: @user2268997 I added some more info to the answer

Comment: would this also work if say %{REQUEST_URI} was /abc/def/foo/bar.html and the rules were in foo directory?

Comment: @user2268997 it'll work no matter what the `%{REQUEST_URI}` is. The point is to extract the part of the URL that is part of the parent directories that the htaccess file is in

Comment: I understand but what would BASE be then?it seems to me as if it is always the part before the first slash.

Comment: @user2268997 given the example, above, where the htaccess file is in the `/abc/` folder, it will be `/abc/`. It will always be `/abc/` no matter what the `%{REQUEST_URI}` is. The BASE is the parent folder(s), always.

Comment: What does the "::" do? Is this some special undocumented syntax?

Comment: @Dalius it's just some delimiter that I can match against, I use "::" because it's extremely unlikely to be a part of the request URI.